# How to want to count number of days in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a scenario where I want to count the number of days. If the worker has a 2 dates with same value then it should be count as a 1 day.Basically to count the total number of days employee worked from home. From the below xml example 3 time blocks, 2 same date and 1 different date, It should count as 2 days.Can anyone help on this

```
  **<wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>
        <wd:Date>2021-10-11</wd:Date>
       <wd:Time_Entry_Code wd:Descriptor="Mobile Working (In-Out)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">TIME_ENTRY_CODE-3-97</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Entry_Code>
    </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>
    <wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>
        <wd:Date>2021-10-11</wd:Date>
        <wd:Reported_Quantity>5</wd:Reported_Quantity>
        <wd:Time_Entry_Code wd:Descriptor="Mobile Working (In-Out)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">TIME_ENTRY_CODE-3-97</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Entry_Code>
    </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>
    <wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>
        <wd:Date>2021-10-12</wd:Date>
        <wd:Reported_Quantity>9</wd:Reported_Quantity>
        <wd:Time_Entry_Code wd:Descriptor="Mobile Working (In-Out)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Time_Code_Reference_ID">TIME_ENTRY_CODE-3-97</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Entry_Code>
    </wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group>**
```

Need output like this
Date- 2021-10-11,2021-10-12
Total Number of days 2

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to do (in XSLT 2.0):

```
count(distinct-values(wd:Time_Blocks_for_Worker_group/wd:Date))
```